# How to achieve plasma effect

Tags: animation

[image]

I want to make this plasma orb with possibility to use it in animation.
Please give some ideas

Comment: I would first try a mess of fabric simulations and turbulence fields, coupled with some emissive / transparent materials.

Comment: Looks a bit like 3D Nebulae (https://youtu.be/4w8_SBxCOxo) with volumetrics. Or maybe like this which was made by particles that emit particles, fluid force field, and textures to colorize the particles (https://youtu.be/kkUC0GQ2SS4). The project files are available for free in the video description.